# How to refresh content after ajax update?

Tags: ajax, jquery, wordpress

I have an admin page for a WordPress plugin that, *thanks to the stackoverflow community*, I've learned how to add ajax calls to all of the functions that add/delete/update questions and answers for the plugin to access.

To help visualize it:
[image]

The next step is to refresh the content after a successful ajax call. Of course I don't want to just re-load the page and I assume refreshing the entire page might cause the answer divs to collapse, which would be undesirable. So refreshing only the related content is best.

The list of questions is generated with the following call to the database:

```
<?php
    $qresult = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ccd_ex_questions ORDER BY sort ASC");
    $qcount = $wpdb->num_rows;
    foreach( $qresult as $key => $qrow ) {
    ?>

        <div id="question<?php echo $qrow->id; ?>" class="display-questions">
            <form id="update-question-<?php echo $qrow->id; ?>" action="" method="post">

                            //question form and content

            </form> {snip...}
```

and the answers are done similar and within the loop generating the list of questions:

```
<?php
$aresult = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ccd_ex_answers WHERE question_id = " . $qrow->id . " ORDER BY sort ASC");
foreach( $aresult as $key => $arow ) {
?>      

    <form id="update-answer-<?php echo $arow->question_id."-".$arow->id; ?>" action="" method="post">

            //answer form and content

    </form> {snip...}
```

The following is one of the jQuery functions using an ajax call to update content:

```
//Add New Answer
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
        $('.asubmitbutton').live("click", function(){   
        var thisasubmit = $(this).data('asubmit');
            $(thisasubmit).submit(function(){

                // Get the proper instance of the form fields for the variables
                var answer = $(this).find('.answer').val();
                var sort = $(this).find('.sort').val();
                var correct = $(this).find('.correct').val();
                var question_id = $(this).find('.question_id').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: {
                        action: 'ccd_ex_insert_answer',
                        answer: answer,
                        sort: sort,
                        correct: correct,
                        question_id: question_id
                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(answer);
                    console.log(sort);
                    console.log(correct);
                    },
                    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            return false;
            });
        });
    });
```

And while we're at it, here's the php function handling this ajax call:

```
//Add an answer
function ccd_ex_insert_answer() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'ccd_ex_answers', array( 
        'answer' => $_POST['answer'],
        'sort' => (int)$_POST['sort'],
        'correct' => (bool)$_POST['correct'],
        'question_id' => (int)$_POST['question_id']
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ccd_ex_insert_answer', 'ccd_ex_insert_answer' );
```

As is, everything works except that changes don't show until the next page re-load.

I presume that I need to add the functions to refresh the data into the success: handler, but I couldn't find an example that spoke to updating the content that is pulled from the database.

**So my question is:** ***How to refresh only the updated content after ajax call and, if possible, maintain the visibility of expanded divs?***

Any help would be greatly appreciated! **Note:** I am barely an intermediate jQuery user and this is my first ajax attempt, so it's better to assume I know nothing if it prevents something important from shooting over my head. ;)

**UPDATE:** I think I am making progress, but still missing something. Problem with the proposed solution is that .html(data) was returning '0'. By removing the line: **url: ajaxurl,** from the ajax call, what is returned now is the entire page content. What I really need to be returned is just the updated content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you want to do a POST to a page/url that will return only the updated content for a certain element (say, with id="id"). For example, you do a call

```
$.ajax({url:"http://example.com/newcontent.php", ...});
```

and the PHP page simply returns

```
<?php echo "thisisnewcontent"; ?>
```

You can then update the html of any DOM element with

```
$("css_selector").html(newContent); // newContent will contain "thisisnewcontent"
```

You should do this update in the ajax success function, where 'data' represents the data that you received from the server.

```
$.ajax({ ..., success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    $("#id").html(data);
});
```

You can read more about ajax() and html() here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax and here
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm getting a '0' though, when it refreshes the content. I also noticed this in the console when using console.log(data). If I use specific fields, like console.log(answer) I can see the correct data, though. Is there something I'm doing wrong that's causing this?

Comment: 'answer' is still the old value of the DOM element, right? So not really an indicator for whether the ajax callback succeeds. Do you use Firefox or Chrome? If so, when you inspect the request-answer, what do you see? Is there any data that gets passed through from the server?

Comment: Yes I do and I've been writing the specific variables to the console throughout this project and noticed that it gives me the updated information. But all along, console.log(data) has returned '0'.

Comment: Just as a test, I changed the line to:   $(thisaupdate).html(answer), but it still just tries to update, but the form fields are replaced with 0.

Comment: If data is '0' then what you get back from the server is '0'. Thus, there probably is an error on the PHP side... You can check that by entering your AJAX url in the browser addressbar and see what you get!

Comment: The result was -1. Being a WordPress site, I'm just using WP's function to call ajax, but I wonder if I'm missing something more. The current ajax updates do take affect.

Comment: I've been reading up on WP and ajax and I think I've done everything right. Being used in the admin area, there's nothing extra to do to make ajax work. I saw mention that -1 means the request is from not logged in user, but I am logged in.

Comment: OK, scratch that... -1 was because I just tried to access the page directly and was not seen as a logged in user.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how WP handles AJAX and requests and everything. 

As for removing the url parameter in the AJAX call: I guess that when you leave out the url paramater it will simply call the current URL, thus loading your current page into 'data'.

Also, I've updated my answer with a more complete process for testing purposes. See if that works, and then try again with WP!